# How to replace deprecated .animation() in SwiftUI?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, ios15

The `.animation()` modifier has been deprecated in iOS 15, but I'm not sure I understand how Xcode's suggested equivalent, `animation(_:value:)`, works.

```
.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2)) // ⚠️'animation' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use withAnimation or animation(_:value:) instead.
```

How would I change my code to get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You need tell Xcode what exactly should be animated! With given a variable that conform to Equatable protocol. That could be State or Binding or any other wrapper that allow you to update the value of it.

***Example:***

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = 200.0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Image(systemName: "ant")
            .font(Font.system(size: 100.0))
            .offset(y: offset)
            .shadow(radius: 10.0)
            .onTapGesture { offset -= 100.0 }
            .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1.0), value: offset)
        
    }
}
```

***Result:***

[image]

Comment: I'm not following this. Can you provide a code example? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I update a sample for you, 1 min

Comment: Ok. I still don't exactly understand why this is different/better (can you explain?), but I got it to work. Thanks.

Comment: I believe Apple just took right decision to deprecated the `.animation(animation:)` because when you and me use that modifier SwiftUI would apply animation to anything that change in value! Which might not our goal! It could gave unwanted or wired animation even! or extra load to CPU! with this new method we are explicitly saying what we need to get animated! also has a down side! Now we should use so many this kind of modifiers to cover all values should be get animated!

Comment: @IgorMuzyka: Please make a question, and I can answer it for you. You can share your question link here. thanks

Comment: @swiftPunk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71864687/animation-was-deprecated-in-ios-15-0-use-withanimation-or-animation-value

Comment: It's best to think of the value argument as the trigger. In this case, when the offset value changes, the animation is started

Answer (score 25):

## UUID

```swift
extension View {
    func withoutAnimation() -> some View {
        self.animation(nil, value: UUID())
    }
}
```

*from:*
[animation(nil) replacement in SwiftUI 3.0 (iOS 15)](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/688947)

> You can use something like this as a general replacement to avoid figuring out a `value`:

Demo:

```swift
/*

.animation(
  Animation
    .easeInOut(duration: 1.5)
    .repeatForever(autoreverses: true)
)

*/

// ⚠️ 'animation' was deprecated in iOS 15.0,
// Use withAnimation or animation(_:value:) instead.


// value: UUID ✅
.animation(
  Animation
    .easeInOut(duration: 1.5)
    .repeatForever(autoreverses: true), 
  value: UUID()
)
```

Comment: haha you made my evening. this uuid loI. I was passing the duration as the value

Comment: I find this answer funny but effective, good job!

Comment: Surprising. This really seems to work.

Answer (score 20):

You can also use the animation by using a boolean as the value.

Example Below:
When you tap the CardView(), it will toggle show which in turn will animate the offset both ways.

```
@State var show = false

CardView()
 .offset(x: 0, y: show ? -100 : -10)
 .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0), value: show)
 .onTapGesture {
   show.toggle()
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Another approach would be to embed ontapGesture in a withAnimation

```
struct SwiftUWithAnimation: View {
@State private var offset: CGFloat = .zero

var body: some View {
    
    Circle()
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
        .offset(x: 0, y: offset)
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.default) {
                offset += 100.0
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for a continuous animation update the value with a timer

```
private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .default).autoconnect()
@State private var start = UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
@State private var end = UnitPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
@State private var val = 1
                
var body: some View {
   LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.pink, .orange]), startPoint: start, endPoint: end)
      .animation(
         Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true).speed(0.5),
         value: val
      )
      .onReceive(timer, perform: { _ in
         val += 1
         self.start = UnitPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
         self.end = UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
      })
}
```

Comment: this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

`.animation` now takes a second argument called `value`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/animation(_:value:)

Comment: How could nil conform to Equatable? can you conform?

Comment: Weirdly, the warning disappears, but now there's an error on the `.rotation3DEffect()` that's above it: "Generic parameter 'V' could not be inferred"

Comment: Well, nil is not working then. See documentation for further help: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/animation(_:value:)