# How do I use animations after the iOS 17 update? ('animation' was deprecated in iOS 15.0)

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

After updating to iOS 17, a `animation` I use throughout my project has changed and now it looks bad.

When using it I had a warning that said:

> 'animation' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use withAnimation or animation(_:value:) instead.

This message didn't seem to effect how it looked when the code ran, but now I think it is impacting it.

Here is my code:

```
TabView(selection: $selectedCategory) {
    
    View1()
        .tag(Category.view1)
        .onAppear {
        }
        .animation(.default)
    
    ImageView()
        .padding(.top)
        .tag(Category.imageView)
        .onAppear {
        }
        .animation(.default)
    
    View3()
        .tag(Category.view3)
        .onAppear {
        }
        .animation(.default)
}
```

The default animation happened when the views in the tab view were initialised. This still happens but instead of a nice natural fade in, it looks messy.

What do I need to replace `.animation(.default)` with in order to return to a nice subtle fade in effect?

I tried to give the animation a boolean value that was set to true in the `.onAppear` but this didn't seem to work.

Here is an example to reproduce:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack {
                
                NavigationLink(destination: View2()) {
                    
                    Text("Tap me")
                        .foregroundStyle(.green)
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Circle()
                .fill(.red)
                .padding()
        }
        .onAppear{
            
        }
        .animation(.default)
    }
}
```

As you can see the animation makes the red circle wobble when it appears, before iOS 17 it faded in. If you take off the animation you will notice the wobble disappears.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69443588/how-to-replace-deprecated-animation-in-swiftui

Comment: @jnpdx I had a look at that but they seem to be for animating things that move. I was using the default animation as a way to fade the view in so that it didn't look so abrupt when it was initialised

Comment: No, it's not just for "things that move". However, they may be a change in behavior between iOS versions that determines if the tabs actually get added/removed from the view hierarchy. What happens if you use `value: selectedCategory`?

Comment: @jnpdx when I try this, no animation occurs

Comment: Sounds like you may have to keep track of which tab is active and show/hide the contents based on that. You can use the `animation(...)` using that value

Comment: @jnpdx I see, although I also had this animation applied to other parts of my project where a tab view isn't present. So for example if I had a view called ImageView() that contained an image in a VStack, then put an .onAppear{} with .animation(.default) attached, the animation worked pre iOS 17. It still animates but it looks strange now.

Comment: Maybe you mean because the default animation type changed in iOS 17? "Looks strange" is pretty vague. I suggest you attach screen captures of the different behavior here and include a [mre].

Comment: @jnpdx yeah I think the default animation has changed. I will edit the question to demonstrate how to reproduce the issue

Comment: @jnpdx I provided a reproducible example. Note the wobble of the red circle when the animation is applied. Before iOS 17 it didn't do this, it had a fade in effect

Comment: iOS 17 changed the default animation to a spring. Before that, it was something like `easeInEaseOut` (I can't remember exactly). You will need to set it to that explicitly now.

Comment: @jnpdx I see, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Instead of `default`, use a different animation type. I suggested above that it may have been `easeInEaseOut` before, but you could do some searching to validate that.

Comment: @jnpdx any version I seem to apply (like .easeInOut) has the same wobble effect, is there something more I need to do?

Comment: Maybe the problem you're seeing is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64566492/swiftui-broken-explicit-animations-in-navigationview

Comment: @jnpdx yeah maybe, I will look into it. It's a weird bug I can't seem to sort out! Definitely has something to do with iOS 17 update though because when I run the same code on iOS 16, it works as expected

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your empty `onAppear`s don't do anything. I'm guessing looking at your code that you may be under the impression that the `animation` applies to the `onAppear` somehow, but that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: @jnpdx oh really? Yes I thought to animate to animate the view an .onAppear was required

Comment: No — you should put actions that should happen on appear inside the closure. Having an empty closure does nothing.